# Java: how to scan classes without knowing package names?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, package, classloading

I'm programming an API that provides functionalities based on annotations on classes. The API would be imported, so it has no knowledge of client's packages. So the question is: **how to scan classes without knowing package names?**

I found these methods:

```
Package.getPackages()
```

but it only returns a subset of packages.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(basePackageName)
```

but is doesn't accept wildcards, such as `*` or `.`.

---

**EDIT** answer to @Rakesh

```
@Component
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationContext appContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application a = new Application();
        String[] beanNames=a.appContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(Run.class);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
            Object bean = a.appContext.getBean(beanName);
            Class<? extends Object> class1 = bean.getClass();
            System.out.println(class1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot inject beans into static fields directly. So remove static.

Comment: Modified, still nullpointer on appContext.

Comment: If you are using spring-boot, Please refer to the following link which demonstrates on how to setup spring application. https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ . The application class is instantiated by you but not by spring. I hope you understand.

Comment: I'm not using Spring-Boot, that was a point missing... If I'm not mistaken Spring-Boot starts a server, I'm not sure it's feasible to make an api that starts a server...

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a custom annotation `@CustomAnnotation` and you have annotated a class `A` with it like this

```
@CustomAnnotation
@Component
public class A{
 ...
}
```

Now you can get those classes like this if you inject application context

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext appContext;
.
.
.
someMethod(){

  string[] beanNames=appContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
   for (val beanName : beanNames) {
      Object bean = appContext.getBean(beanName);
      Class<? extends Object> class1 = bean.getClass();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm making a stand-alone application, not a web application, do @Autowired and ApplicationContext work as well?

Comment: I get NullPointer on appContext.

Comment: did you annotate your current class with @Component?

Comment: yes I did annotate my calss with @Component. Anyway it's applicationContext that is not injected, not the beans.

Comment: Guess the applicationcontext is not injected properly, Can you share your code?

Comment: Answered in question.